# Persistence space

Tags: updates, disk-usage, usb-installation

This isn't a problem, but rather a request for information. Is there any documentation available which explains what goes, and what doesn't go, into the 'persistence' area of a disk? In particular, I'm after knowing how to free space in the area as I'm forever getting 'space shortage' messages.

The context is that I've installed 12.04 LTS on a USB3 stick with 64Gb of space, using the Startup Disk Creator. I'm doing this because my hard disk boot sector is knackered, and I can't boot up Windoze, so I have to run Ubuntu from USB or DVD. I set the persistent area to its max size of 4Gb, and it's loaded as the volume /cow (which got me scratching my head as to the name). df reports that it's over 90% used. I've installed some 430Mb of updates, which I'd thought would write to the main system volume, but perhaps has gone into the persistent area. I've also installed a few utilities which almost certainly have gone into there.

The 'meta-context' is that I'm trying to gain control of Ubuntu after a couple of years away from Linux.

Comment: Note that when you install updates, `apt` will cache the packages that are downloaded in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. You can remove them with `sudo apt-get clean`.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, that's a great tip. I ran that just now and immediately df reported 20% less usage in the persistent space.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you write/install goes to the persistent storage.  It's entire purpose for existing is to allow you to write files and keep them when you reboot, since otherwise they would be kept in ram and lost on shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can have persistence as a **casper-rw** file with max 4GB or a casper-rw partition with space only limited by the size of the drive, (Use ext filesysten).

You can also have persistence as a 4GB **home-rw** file or unlimited ext partition.

The same thing generally goes into **casper-rw** in a persistent install as goes into "**/**" partition in a Full install and into **home-rw** file as goes into "**/home**" partition in a Full install.

I have tried but never succeeded in saving proprietary drivers, (Nvidia, ATI), (and something else, that I can't remember right now but will edit this post later).

Edit:
You also can not save kernel updates with a persistent install.